# login page not working

Tags: redirect, login, dashboard

i moved my wordpress website from old server to new server without any problem.

when i log in to dashboard it is not working. Page becomes refresh, checked with password right and wrong. It doesn't matter.

Even it is not showing any error.

i changed urls in database with new one (site url and home).

1. i checked on my local server using same username and password, it is working properly.
2. Rename theme folders except twentytwelve, but no success.
3. Rename plugin folders.
4. Deleted cookies and restart browser.
5. enabled `WP_DEBUG` get error on both dashboard and website

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/popup-with-fancybox/popup-with-fancybox.php
>   on line 63
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/popup-with-fancybox/popup-with-fancybox.php
>   on line 63

6. Removed plugin from database (`active_plugin`) and enable `WP_DEBUG` i get error only on

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php on line 418

7. added `define('RELOCATE',true);`
8. removed `define('RELOCATE',true)` and deactivated plugin from database. 
   But nothing happend.
9. as per @ryan changes

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php on line 418
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php on line 431
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 913
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 914
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/projectname/public_html/wp-login.php:1) in
>   /home/projectname/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 915

10. Removed `function.php` and tried.

Is it server problem? or wordpress version problem or database problem?

website is now live so i dont want to take any risk,

what to do for login

Comment: I have moved all comments to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17701/discussion-on-question-by-prashant-login-page-not-working), because this comment thread was way to noisy.

Comment: Finally My problem solved. Thanx all. I uploaded wordpress from cpanal and then upload only needed files (images, wp-content etc). thanx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OP's solution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18052414#18052414) was to replace core files:

> @RyanLoremIpsum @toscho @Robert Finally My problem solved. Thanx all.
>   **I uploaded wordpress from cpanal and then upload only needed files
>   (images, wp-content etc).**

Comment: what is mean by op's?

Comment: Original Poster